# Query to find the sum of rows in one table which equals to one or more row on another table

Tags: sql, algorithm, postgresql

I need help with a query. The task is to get rows of one table whose amount will sum up to become a value in another table and vice versa.

An illustration of the example:

```
Table 1:                                Table2:

  r_id   |    r_date   |   r_amt          p_id   |    p_date   |   p_amt    
---------+-------------+--------        ---------+-------------+--------
    1    |  2/23/2012  |   200              1    |  3/22/2012  |   450
---------+-------------+--------        ---------+-------------+--------
    2    |  3/21/2012  |   100              2    |  5/25/2012  |   530
---------+-------------+--------        ---------+-------------+--------
    3    |  4/12/2012  |   300              3    |  5/26/2012  |   700
---------+-------------+--------        ---------+-------------+--------
    4    |  4/18/2012  |   250              4    |  5/26/2012  |   40
---------+-------------+--------        ---------+-------------+--------
    5    |  5/20/2012  |   130
---------+-------------+--------
    6    |  5/21/2012  |   740
---------+-------------+--------
```

Now these test datas are in such a way that, few rows of table 1 will sum up to become one row in table 2 and vice versa.

I want a query to analyse the above data in such a way that the sum of records in one table will be equal to one row in the other.

After the analyze is complete it should feed the data to a new table like this.

Lets call this table `match`

```
  m_id   |    tbl1     |   tbl2   | match_type
---------+-------------+----------+-----------
    1    |    1,4      |   1      |   n-1
---------+-------------+----------+-----------
    1    |    2,3,5    |   2      |   n-1
---------+-------------+----------+-----------
    1    |     6       |   3,4    |   1-n
---------+-------------+----------+-----------
```

Right now, I am calculating the sum of each table and entering on a temporary table then comparing with that table to get the above result. But for more than 10 rows the queries become really slow and hang my development server.

#### <kbd>[Link to my test Queries](http://developers.mrnepal.com/qtest.sql)</kbd>

What is the efficient way to perform this task?

Comment: `match` is a table or the result of the query?

Comment: @JW., It is a table, the result of the query is added to this table.

Comment: What if there are multiple solutions? Or only partial solutions (that correlate only a subset from both tables)?

Comment: @ypercube, I am planning on something like this: After looking for 1-n and n-1 matches, Looks for the remaining rows on the both table to calculate n-n matches.

Comment: I meant that a specific instance of the problem may have many (thousands or millions) solutions. Other instances may have no exact solution and only partial solutions or no solution at all. Unless of course the total sum of both tables is guaranteed to be equal, so there is always the trivial n-n solution of all rows in one set.

Comment: I'm not sure but this looks like it could be a NP-complete problem (or harder), so I don't think SQL is the right choice for solving it.

Comment: Yes, the sum of both tables have to be equal in some point. What do you suggest, if SQL cannot solve this. And I don't understand what NP-Complete means.

Comment: **[NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete)**

Comment: I didn't say that you can't solve it in SQL. But it will probably require recursive queries and back-tracking techniques. I think the best route is to first find an algorithm that will solve your problem and then decide which language you will implement it. I suggest you leave the question here but tag with "algorithm" (and maybe remove the "postgres" and "stored-procedures" tags) and if you don't get a useful answer, migrate the question to [Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ypercube, OK, it is not entirely automated task. Human intervention is indeed needed. First 1-1 Matches are done, the 1-n and n-1 and lastly n-n. After each successfully match and affirmation the number cases will decrease itself. So in a point this should be a solvable task.

Comment: What is the role of these dates? They seem to be totally ignored in the matches.

Comment: @wildplasser, Those are used to calculate the closest match in terms of date among the records.

Comment: Looks like the stable marriage problem to me. After omitting the ban on multi-person marriages, that is... BTW: there are ~N! partitions of the Ltable and ~M! partitions of the Rtable, the problem will be finding matches between these partitions. Round-based matching (like in the stable marriage problem Gale-Shapley deferred match) will probably be the only practical way.

Comment: @wildplasser, I have no idea what you just said to me.

Comment: Could you paste your queries?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, Dont you think it is a data-mining task?

Comment: No, it's the knapsack problem.

Comment: Why are all the answers crammed into the comments? Several of you seem to have solutions which this margin is too narrow to contain...

Comment: @IMSoP, Where is the answer?

Comment: @Starx I was referring in particular to wildplasser's comment, which hints at a particular solution without really explaining what it is.

Comment: Imagining the performance-killing possibilities here.....

Comment: To expand on that....  Your intermediary results are going to be more than n! x m! where n is the number of rows in the first table and m is the number of rows in the second table.  Moreover you will have to do one scan per row of each table.  If you have 10 rows in each table, this suggests checking more than 13168189440000 possibilities.

Comment: @ChrisTravers, WOW? That's big.

Comment: Actually if only one side only had 1 row and the other can have many then 10 rows on each table still only generates approx 7-8M intermediate results.  In your case it would be small but it is still a *lot* and there is no way to narrow it down.

Comment: @ChrisTravers, So suggest me something. How can I do?

Comment: I may try to put together a working solution later but the basis is, generate all possible combinations on all tables, and then compare across. This would require with recursive CTEs with some fun tricks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so here is a rough answer.  I have not tested it.  Recursive CTE's have some odd gotchas and it is possible I ran into one, but this should get you going.  There may also be some performance tuning possible but this may get you going.

The algorithm roughly goes as follows:

1. Generate all permutations of all rows
2. Compare each permutation on one side with each row on the other

The first will be done with recursive CTE's.  The second with a simple join.

```
WITH RECURSIVE table1_combos as (
     SELECT r_id as last_id, r_id::text as path, r_amt as amount
       FROM table1
  UNION ALL 
     SELECT r.r_id as last_id, p.path || ',' || r_id::text, p.amount + r_amt
       FROM table1_combos p
 CROSS JOIN table1 r
      WHERE r.r_id < p.last_id
),
RECURSIVE table2_combos AS (
     SELECT p_id as last_id, p_id::text as path, p_amt as amount
       FROM table2
  UNION ALL 
     SELECT p_id AS last_id, p.path || ',' || p_id::text, p.amount + p_amt
       FROM table2_combos p
 CROSS JOIN table2 
      WHERE p_id < p.last_id
)
SELECT c.path, p_id::text, c.amount, 'n-1' as type
  FROM table1_combos c
  JOIN table2 t ON c.amount = p_amt
UNION ALL
SELECT r_id::text, c.path, c.amount, '1-n' as type
  FROM table2_combos c
  JOIN table1 t ON r_amt = c.amount;
```

As for performance the fundamental problem is that you will have a great deal of space to search.  There isn't a reasonably easy way to do that, unfortunately.  The combination space is extremely large, and it gets much larger with each additional row you add.

Hmmm revisiting my estimates.  A 10 row table should generate 6.3 million combinations, while an 11 row table should generate 68.6 million combinations.  In PostgreSQL you can check the number of expected combinations with the following SQL statement:

```
select sum(factorial(11)/factorial(f)) from generate_series(1, 11) f;
```

For an 11 row table.  Note as follows:

```
select sum(factorial(100)/factorial(f)) from generate_series(1, 100) f;

         sum                                                                    

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------
 1603607401161831447335715093560135199544316103019165207641822220922316539151565
30909999021448995531507013709811500779735358328288932830176709764490323163992001
.00000000000000000000
(1 row)
```

If you have a 100 row table you will be waiting for a while.....

Now you might be able to further address this by bounding the CTE itself saying "stop when you reach the max of the other table" for example.

Comment: This is probably the best way to go.  Some additional thoughts: for large result sets, it may be more efficient to make a temp table for the calculations; you may be able to speed up some as written by adding some logic to pre-filter impossible results.  If the value to be summed is larger than the result value it can't be part of the solution.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to try to join with the other table and don't join with itself if there's a match. Maybe do n iterations and then stop to remove the numbers that already were matched?

Comment: @JakubKania actually I think the better option would be to stop when a certain total has been reached, like the max of the other table.  However this provides a basis for allowing the db to approach this as a set rather than a bunch of individual rows, and the specifics will depend on the data being joined.